# 14 bit binary to 4 digit(16bit) bcd

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to make 14 bit binary to 4 digit bcd. But it does not work well. Give me some ideas

here is my code

```
module binary2BCD(
    input [13:0] binary,
    output reg [15:0] o
    ); 
reg [29:0]shift=0; 
integer i; 
always@(*) begin
    shift = 30'b0;
     shift[13:0] = binary;
     for (i=0; i<14; i=i+1) begin
            if (shift[17:14] > 4'b0100)
                 shift[17:14] = shift[17:14] + 4'b0011;
            if (shift[21:18] > 4'b0100)
                 shift[21:18] = shift[17:14] + 4'b0011;
            if (shift[25:22] > 4'b0100)
                 shift[25:22] = shift[17:14] + 4'b0011;        
            if (shift[29:26] > 4'b0100)
                 shift[29:26] = shift[17:14] + 4'b0011;
        shift = shift << 1;
 end
  o= {shift[29:26], shift[25:22], shift[21:18], shift[17:14]};
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty good. I think the only problem is that you are incrementing the wrong BCD digits.

```
if (shift[21:18] > 4'b0100)
    shift[21:18] = shift[17:14] + 4'b0011;
                         ^^^^^ should be 21:18
```